# Abrir KB sin objetos recientes

Tags: genexus

Al abrir una KB siempre se abre con los objetos que quedaron abiertos de la última vez que se cerró.

¿Cómo es para que esto no ocurra?

En mi caso estoy abriendo la KB desde un .bat:

```
@ECHO OFF

"C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus16 U2\genexus.exe" /install
start "Genexus 16 U2" "C:\Program Files(x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus16U2\genexus.exe" /NoLastKB /NoWorkspace
```

Probé agregando el /NoWorkspace sin éxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quedó la implementación de /NoRecentObjects para resolver lo que precisabas.
Está a partir de Genexus V17 Upgrade 8. Actualmente en [preview](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?49616,GeneXus%2017%20Upgrade%208) a liberar en Feb/2022.

Más info: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?6740,GeneXus+command+line+parameters

Answer (score 0):

No hay un flag para eso. Lo que puedes hacer es eliminar (o renombrar) el workspace.
Los últimos objetos abiertos se guardan por KB/Usuario en un XML que tiene la lista.

Si vas al directorio de tu KB y ahí el usuario, encontrarás un archivo .workspace que contiene eso.

Ejemplo: c:\MyKB\MyUser\MyKB.workspace
Renombrado o borrado ese, al abrir la KB no se abren los objetos.

De pronto es algo que se implementa en el futuro, en este sentido sería bueno saber el motivo: ¿cuál es la utilidad de no abrir los últimos objetos abiertos en esa KB por ese usuario?

Comment: Probé borrando o renombrando el archivo .workspace, pero cada vez que abro la KB me genera uno como el que existía antes y vuelve a abrir los objetos. También probé renombrando la carpeta del usuario, y me crea una nueva carpeta también con el archivo workspace ya generado. El motivo es que abrí un objeto y cuando quise visualizar el web form hizo tildar GX. Cada vez que abro la KB, abre ese mismo objeto en el web form y se tilda todo. ¿Para qué sirve entonces el flag /NoWorkspace que se indica en https://tinyurl.com/yc45ueab?

Comment: Hay un tema de nombres: el /NoWorkSpace lo que hace es que resetea cómo tenés distribuidas las ventanas del IDE al "default". No cambia esa lista. Sí, es confuso que se llamen "workspace" ambas cosas e incluso cuando abres la  KB dice "loading workspace".
El funcionamiento que tienes es el que describes (se crea el archivo de nuevo).
Entendí el propósito de "no abrirlos" de todos modos parecería que hay un objeto "mal" ahí porque no lo puedes abrir, ese es el problema de fondo. Capaz es bueno reportar eso a soporte (si no lo hiciste).